# get router's IP Address in ionic2 - Non Native Plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, network-interface

Plugin:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-networkinterface
```

Code:

```
networkinterface.getIpAddress((ip) => {
    console.log(ip);
});
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getIPAddress' of undefined
```

Now here neither I have provide any **provider** nor any **import**, so how does it work in ionic 2 ?
It's not A native plugin. But this plugin is working in ionic 2 also according to this [link](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/cordova-plugin-network-interface-issue/51439)

Package.json :

```
{
  "name": "ionic-hello-world",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
  "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
  "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
  "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
  "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
},
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.4.8",
"@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
"@angular/core": "2.4.8",
"@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
"@angular/http": "2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
"@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
"@ionic-native/core": "3.1.0",  
"@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^3.4.2",
"@ionic-native/network": "^3.4.2",
"@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.1.0",
"@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.1.0",
"@ionic-native/toast": "^3.4.4",
"@ionic/app-scripts": "^1.2.2",
"@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
"ionic-angular": "2.3.0",
"ionic-native": "^2.9.0",
"ionicons": "3.0.0",
"rxjs": "5.0.1",
"sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
"zone.js": "0.7.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.2.2",
  "typescript": "2.0.9"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
"cordova-plugin-whitelist",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar",
"cordova-plugin-console",
"cordova-plugin-device",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard"
   ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": [],
   "description": "Test"
}
```

Latest Code File :

```
declare var networkinterface: any;

    @Component({
     templateUrl: 'app.html'
   })
   export class MyApp {
     public rootPage:any = HomePage;

    constructor(private platform: Platform,private statusBar: StatusBar,private splashScreen: SplashScreen, private network: Network, private iab: InAppBrowser, private http: Http, private toast: Toast) {

    platform.ready().then(() => {
      networkinterface.getWiFiIPAddress((ip) => {
                console.log(ip);
    });
 }
```

Comment: Can you show your `package.json`?

Comment: are you using a native plugin or what? URL of it?

Comment: it's not a native plugin . [link](https://github.com/salbahra/cordova-plugin-networkinterface)

Comment: @Sampath JSON file is too long for this comment box what to do ?

Comment: you can put that on your original post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use it like below after installing the non-native plugin.

> This method (`getIpAddress()`) is deprecated and uses the
>   `getWiFiIPAddress()` method.

```
     declare let networkinterface: any;

        @Component({
          ...
        })
        export class TestPage {

          ...

          getIpAddress() {
            networkinterface.getWiFiIPAddress((ip) => {
            console.log(ip);
        });
      }
    }
```

Comment: error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: networkinterface is not defined
ReferenceError: networkinterface is not defined

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: first i tried that only, but was not working so i changed it to `var`

Comment: Actually I don't need any page component because I am creating a webview and my startup time is maximum 5 second , so that is not an issue. It's just that this plugin is working in Ionic1 and for ionic2 I need to give **Provider** and **import** some files, and that i am not doing here so what could be the possible way

Comment: There is no provider or import for the non-native plugins.You have to use it like above.

Comment: Can you share the plugin Url?

Comment: I think this plugin has an issue recently.Same issue no answer yet.https://github.com/salbahra/cordova-plugin-networkinterface/issues/18

Comment: so what else i can do ?  Any idea ?

Comment: If the author of this plugin has not given a solution means you have to find a different plugin.

Comment: Now i am using this plugin's Java file and checking on studio if it's working then i'll try to create custom plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using external url:

```
 async function getIP(){

  const repsIP = await fetch('https://api.ipify.org/?format=json');

  const data = await repsIP.json();

  return data;

  }
```

Wherever you want, call this function:

```
this.getIP().then(data => this.ipAddress = data.ip);
```